# CSS: Table Sizing Issue (caption/tr/th/td)

Tags: css, html, html-table, width, caption

Working on specifically a pricing table chart. When the screen is maximized, all of the elements (caption/tr/th/td) are spaced out correctly and if within the background-color. Once the screen begins to get smaller, the elements stay spaced out and stretch past the border and the page itself.

How do I get the elements to stay within the size of the table and it's background through-out screen resizing?

HTML5:

```
<table>
                    <caption>Cracked Screens &amp; Hardware Pricing</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>header 1</th>
                        <th>header 2</th>
                        <th>header 3</th>
                        <th>header 4</th>
                        <th>header 5</th>
                        <th>header 6</th>
                        <th>header 7</th>
                        <th>header 8</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th colspan="8">iPhone</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Side 1</th>
                        <td>$250</td>
                        <td>$48</td>
                        <td>$65</td>
                        <td>$58</td>
                        <td>$50</td>
                        <td>Call</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$65</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Side 2</th>
                        <td>$150</td>
                        <td>$48</td>
                        <td>$65</td>
                        <td>$70</td>
                        <td>$47</td>
                        <td>$60</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$63</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Side 3</th>
                        <td>$100</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$58</td>
                        <td>$55</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$53</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Side 4</th>
                        <td>$100</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$55</td>
                        <td>$55</td>
                        <td>$50</td>
                        <td>$55</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$58</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Side 5</th>
                        <td>$100</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$53</td>
                        <td>$57</td>
                        <td>$45</td>
                        <td>$50</td>
                        <td>$41</td>
                        <td>$60</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-self: center;
align-self: center;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
background: #ECF0F1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
-webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
border-radius: 0.3em;
padding: 1.3em;
width: 90%;
}

table>caption{
width: 30em;
height: 2em;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
}

th{
height: 2em;
font-size: 1em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
text-align: center;
}

tr{
max-width: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

td{
min-width: 100px;
}

td:hover{
color: #008000;
}

.call{
background-color: #B6B6B4;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick... let me know if I missed anything?

Reason:

You need to add min-width to the `<td>` and `<th>` tags so they won't resize to small pushing your text to the next line.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8dthkb3g/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
            <th>header 4</th>
            <th>header 5</th>
            <th>header 6</th>
            <th>header 7</th>
            <th>header 8</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Side 1</th>
            <td>$250</td>
            <td>$48</td>
            <td>$65</td>
            <td>$58</td>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>Call</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$65</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Side 2</th>
            <td>$150</td>
            <td>$48</td>
            <td>$65</td>
            <td>$70</td>
            <td>$47</td>
            <td>$60</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Side 3</th>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$58</td>
            <td>$55</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$53</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Side 4</th>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$55</td>
            <td>$55</td>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>$55</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$58</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Side 5</th>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$53</td>
            <td>$57</td>
            <td>$45</td>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>$41</td>
            <td>$60</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS (index.css)

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;  
    background: #1E67CB;
}
section{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}
table{
    background: #ECF0F1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
}
tr{
    text-align: center;
}
th{
    min-width: 62px;
}
td{
    min-width: 62px;
}
```

Comment: I see your JSFiddle, and I added min-width and still the background isn't sticking. heres the jsfiddle of it added... I can't see what the difference is...

https://jsfiddle.net/zh3btgvn/

Comment: When I shrink the screen, the table and page does as well. Showing overflow and elements out of scope...

Comment: @blackRob4953 so on your jsfiddle it looks like your min-width for the <th> tags is 62px which is what it is for mine... but yours should be 67px... so if you change that it will stop the header dropping the number to the next line...

Comment: @blackRob4953 adding min-width on the <td> and <th> tag allows the table to resize down from the inside (best-way).... the other way you could do it is adding min-width on the table itself... therefore the table won't shrink past that limit... then you don't have to add it on the <th> and <td>

Comment: It's still overflowing outside of my table background. do I multiply the 67px by my 9 rows to get the table min-width?

Comment: @blackRob4953 I don't see it overflowing the table... when you shrink it the text doesn't go outside the table right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88404/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-blackrob4953).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use bootstrap to achieve this. You can check each screen size according to the grids of bootstrap if you want to make it responsive by overwriting the original bootstrap css.

You can check out the bootstrap grid system [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Simply search for **@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)** in the bootstrap original css and overwrite it by setting your own properties in your styles section, in your case, set the table dimensions with respect to the screen size.